# Spring JPA Composite key: This class does not define an IdClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

Get an error on app run 
`This class [class com.socnetw.socnetw.model.Relationship] does not define an IdClass`. 
When I used EntityManager all worked well. But now I switch to Spring `CrudRepository<T, T>` and get this error. I know problem's about mapping primary key constraint. But what exactly I should to do I dont know. Could some one help hendle it?

Relationship.class

```
@Table(name = "RELATIONSHIP")
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Relationship implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long userIdFrom;
    @Id
    private Long userIdTo;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RelationshipStatus status;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDate friendsRequestDate;
}
```

RelationshipRepository.class just for case

```
public interface RelationshipRepository extends CrudRepository<Relationship, Long> {

    @Query(value = "some query", nativeQuery = true)
    Long findAmountOfFriends(@Param("userId") Long userId);  
    ...other methods

}
```

DataInit.class

```
@Component
public class DataInit implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PostRepository postRepository;
    private RelationshipRepository relationshipRepository;
    private MessageRepositorys messageRepository;

    public DataInit(UserRepository userRepository, PostRepository postRepository, RelationshipRepository relationshipRepository, MessageRepositorys messageRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
        this.relationshipRepository = relationshipRepository;
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
     //here I create users and save them
    ...
    ...
    ...
    userRepository.save(someUser);


    relationshipRepository.save(relationship);
    messageRepository.save(message);

    }
}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataInit' defined in file [C:\Users\tpmylov\Desktop\learning\Projects\socnetw\target\classes\com\socnetw\socnetw\bootstrap\DataInit.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relationshipRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.socnetw.socnetw.model.Relationship] does not define an IdClass
...
...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relationshipRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.socnetw.socnetw.model.Relationship] does not define an IdClass
```

Answer (score 26):

You have a composite key:

```
@Id
private Long userIdFrom;
@Id
private Long userIdTo;
```

For this you have to create an IdClass:

```
public class RelationshipId implements Serializable {
    private Long userIdFrom;
    private Long userIdTo;

    // Getter and Setter
}
```

Then you can use it on the class

```
@IdClass(RelationshipId.class)
public class Relationship ....
```

And on the Repository:

```
public interface RelationshipRepository 
                 extends CrudRepository<Relationship, RelationshipId> {

    @Query(value = "some query", nativeQuery = true)
    Long findAmountOfFriends(@Param("userId") Long userId);  
    ...other methods
}
```

Read more about composite keys in the official Hibernate documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

Answer (score 7):

Your entity `Relationship` declaration assumes usage of [composite primary key](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite). So, you should correct your entity in the following way:

```java
@Table(name = "RELATIONSHIP")
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@IdClass(RelationshipPK.class)
public class Relationship implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long userIdFrom;
    @Id
    private Long userIdTo;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RelationshipStatus status;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDate friendsRequestDate;
}
```

and then `RelationshipPK`:

```java
public class RelationshipPK implements Serializable {

    private Long userIdFrom;
    private Long userIdTo;

    public RelationshipPK(Long userIdFrom, Long userIdTo) {
        this.userIdFrom = userIdFrom;
        this.userIdTo = userIdTo;
    }

    public RelationshipPK() {
    }

    //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
            return false;
        }
        RelationshipPK pk = (RelationshipPK) o;
        return Objects.equals( userIdFrom, pk.userIdFrom ) &&
                Objects.equals( userIdTo, pk.userIdTo );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash( userIdFrom, userIdTo );
    }
}
```

and your `CrudRepository` should have the following view:

```java
public interface RelationshipRepository extends CrudRepository<Relationship, RelationshipPK>
{

    @Query(value = "some query", nativeQuery = true)
    Long findAmountOfFriends(@Param("userId") Long userId);  
    ...other methods

}
```

Actually, hibernate allows to declare a composite key and without this stuff. This is so called [composite identifiers with associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations). But it is necessary for the following [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) methods:

```java
public interface CrudRepository<T,ID> extends Repository<T,ID>
{
   void deleteById(ID id);

   boolean existsById(ID id);

   Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);

   Optional<T>  findById(ID id);

   // ...
}
```