# This class does not define an IdClass foreign key

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud

I am using the productid as a foreign key in my phone table. I don't know what to write in the id part of the PhoneRepository. Because gives an error

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {

@Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long productID;
...
```

Phone.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(Product.class)
public class Phone implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "productID")
private Product product;
...
```

PhoneRepository.java

```
 @Repository
 public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, Product>{  //I tried Long

  }
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class 
com.test.project.data.entity.prod.Phone] does not define an IdClass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JPA Composite key: This class does not define an IdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414409/spring-jpa-composite-key-this-class-does-not-define-an-idclass)

Comment: No. I guess that's not the problem

Comment: I think you must also declare the fields from the Id class (`Product`) in the entity `Phone` and annotate them with @Id. But `IdClass` is to be used for composite primary keys.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers#derived-identifiers) will help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @IdClass annotation on Product because you are not customizing an id provider.

Also remove @Id from product on Phone and add a phoneID as below:

```
@Id
private long phoneID;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "productID", referencedColumnName = "productID")
private Product product;
```

Comment: If I remove the id it gives an error because there is no id in the table  "No identifier specified for entity: com.test.project.data.entity.prod.Phone"

Comment: Add a separate id field on Phone, such as phoneID, annotated with @Id .