# Relationship table mapped as entity in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to map one specific many to many table on my database as an entity in JPA (cause I have some specific attributes on my relationship table and I wanted to retrieve this as the class attributes two). But having issues while declaring the IDs.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_plan")
public class UserPlan implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    private Plan plan;
    
    private Integer billingDay;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BillingType billingType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PlanStatus planStatus;
}
```

The application starts successfully but when I try to map some repository to manage this table, Hibernate throws an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.demo.domain.model.UserPlan] does not define an IdClass
```

How can I use the JPA entity annotation to manage this relationship table? Is it possible?

I cannot simply declare one property in the user class of `Plan` model and mark it as @ManyToMany, cause the plan table does not have the property that I need to execute some operations, which are declared on `UserPlan` class, also I cannot move these properties to `Plan` class, cause the Plan table is just a template of a plan, and the `UserPlan` have all the specific data (billingDay, billingType and planStatus).

JPA supports relationship tables as a Java class? Or it can be mapped only as a property?

Thanks

Comment: Note that it is best practice _not_ to use `@Data` or `@EAHC` on entity classes, specifically because what defines an "entity" is having an identity distinct from any of its data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multiple `@Id` annotations. To do so you need to create PrimaryKey class:

```
public class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    private User user;
    private Plan plan;
    
    // Getter and Setter
}
```

And you need to add `@IdClass(PrimaryKey.class)` annotation to your entity class.

If you have a `Repository` don't forget to change id type to PrimaryKey:

```
public interface YourRepository
             extends SomeRepositoryInterface<UserPlan, PrimaryKey> {
    //...
}
```

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414409/spring-jpa-composite-key-this-class-does-not-define-an-idclass)